# I hit a bug when trying to report a bug regarding Visual Studio to connect.microsoft.com

Tags: microsoft

Having created an account and signed in I go to `https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio` and receive this message:

[image: screenshot]

The only "submit a bug" button I can see is on the `microsoft.net` native page `connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/MSNetNative` and that just goes to an error page ... a bug trying to submit the bug!:

[image: second screenshot]

Maybe there's a submit a bug option elsewhere that works.

[by contrast]
If I click on PowerShell in the directory then there's a button to submit a bug. If I click on Visual Studio I get a message:

> you have been invited to join a private NDA program for Visual Studio, you can view specific content by selecting from the dropdown titled "Programs" located at the top of this page.

at that point I've no idea what to click next, but clicking programs doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: The "submit a bug" option has "a bug"! Classic! (Although, for some reason, this doesn't actually surprise me with MS sites!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sign out

THEN go there

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

And there is a submit a bug button

[image]

Click that "submit a bug"

Then there is a sign in page. Sign in

Then you get a form to submit the bug

[image]